# Equal spacing max width nav

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

1. The spacing in between each link is equal
2. There is a divider right in the middle of the empty space in between each link
3. The menu is fluid
4. When there is no more space on the page the long items break into multi line but the space in between each link stays equal (This is the tricky one)

The issue I keep running into is that once something needs to break onto multiple lines the spacing in between each link is no longer equal.

- In example 1 you can see what happens when the text breaks onto
  multiple lines (The space in between the links is no longer equal)
- In example 2 you can see that when the links don't break onto
  multiple lines the spacing is correct.

[image]

I've tried countless ways to try and get this to work and nothing seems to make the anchors behave once the text drops into multiple lines. (If only inline would behave)

**Example 1**

```css
.nav-section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
}
.nav-section__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav-section__item-divider {
  min-width: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.nav-section__link {
  display: inline;
  background: orange;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-section">
  <div class="nav-section__list">

    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">Super long12312 link blah</a>
    <div class="nav-section__item-divider"></div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">Semi long link blah blah blah</a>
    <div class="nav-section__item-divider"></div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">long link</a>

  </div>
</nav>
```

**Example 2**

```css
.nav-section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
}
.nav-section__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav-section__item-divider {
  min-width: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.nav-section__link {
  display: inline;
  background: orange;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-section">
  <div class="nav-section__list">

    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">Super long12312</a>
    <div class="nav-section__item-divider"></div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">Semi long link blah</a>
    <div class="nav-section__item-divider"></div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">long</a>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: There's nothing you can really do...that's the way the line box model works.

Comment: I know it's the DESIGN...but in practical terms you are overthinking this. No-one will notice and if they do, they won't care.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I kind of figured but hoped there might be something I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is simply a function of how HTML wraps long content. If you look at the spacing between the links using an HTML inspector, the spacing is still the same but the wrapped content does not span the full width of the link.

You could try to use the `text-align:justify` property. That will make the spacing between links appear the way you want, but will increase the space between each word in the link.

```css
.nav-section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
}
.nav-section__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav-section__item-divider {
  min-width: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.nav-section__link {
  display: inline;
  background: orange;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-section">
  <div class="nav-section__list">

    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">Super long 12312 12312</a>
    <div class="nav-section__item-divider"></div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">Semi long link blah</a>
    <div class="nav-section__item-divider"></div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-section__item  nav-section__link">long</a>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great suggestion Khris - doesn't look the greatest but at least it's an option.